# Unable to set UDP source address in bind

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I am trying to set the source UDP port for a new socket. I use bind to do so. Here is my code:

```
struct sockaddr_in udpAddr, udpAssignedAddr;
socklen_t sizeOfSockAddr;
struct newSocket _newSocket, errorSocket;
socklen_t  udpAddrLen;

int udpFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);  
if (udpFd > 0) {
  udpAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  udpAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  udpAddr.sin_port = htons(41000);
  udpAddrLen = sizeof(udpAddr); 

  if (bind(udpFd, (struct sockaddr *)&udpAddr, udpAddrLen) < 0) 
    perror("Error");

  sizeOfSockAddr =  sizeof(udpAssignedAddr);
  getsockname(udpFd, (struct sockaddr *)&udpAssignedAddr, &udpAddrLen);

  printf("%s - %d \n", inet_ntoa(udpAssignedAddr.sin_addr), 
                       ntohs(udpAssignedAddr.sin_port) );
}
```

I get the same port number (10400) displayed which is NOT what is assigned, no matter how many times I run it. However, if I set to 0 instead of 41000, then a different port number is displayed each time the program is executed.

Comment: Consider this: `printf("%hd\n", htons(41000));`. And after copying your code and getting it compiling, I get `0.0.0.0 - 41000` as expected. Are you sure your real code is using `ntohs()` when displaying the address and port?

Comment: Minor nit -- 0 is a perfectly valid return value from `socket`. The check should be if `udpFd != -1`. (In practice, you'll only get a zero back if the process has no stdin descriptor.)

Comment: @Shawn That is my real code... I mean I trimmed a few error checks.  printf("%hd\n", htons(41000)) outputs 10400. At least I got the relationship. Thanks...  Any length of structure issue?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Yes. U r right. Thanks for the info though not related to the problem directly.

Comment: @Shawn  My sincere apologies... While trimming the code, I made a mistake... just realized it. I had missed the ntohs(...)  If u post this as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.